# Не срабатывает onafterprint (как я понял вопрос в браузере)

Tags: javascript, кроссбраузерность, print

После запуска открывается окно печати, но если его закрыть, то `onafterprint` не срабатівает. Если повторно нажать `Ctrl+P`(что есть горячая клавиша печати) и снова закрыть, то все работает.

Вопрос: почему работает при втором разе, и не работает при первом? Как сделать чтобы работало при первом?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  window.print();
  
  window.onafterprint = function(){
    alert(123);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

update

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MACTEPwar/t57gh0sm/) это то что мне нужно.

В `chrome` открывается (в бредовом виде) и закрывается как надо.
В `ff` отрывается нормально, закрывается со второй попытки.
В `Edge` открывается и закрывается сразу же.

Теперь новый вопрос...как сделать на все браузеры нормально работающее?

Comment: Всё работает. Закрываю окно печати и получаю алерт в `123`.

Comment: @Denis640Kb мб браузер...я в `ff` пробую